# How to combine VS Code workbench and token colours from two different themes

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, themes, editor, customization

I've recently moved to VS Code from Sublime Text 3, and I'm wondering whether - as of the time of asking this question - there's a way to use the .tmTheme file I was using for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text.

I understand that this will involve creating a custom theme as VS Code doesn't inherently separate UI styling from syntax highlighting like Sublime and Atom do, but does VS Code at least provide any way to automate the process of combining the UI (which I think is known as the workbench in VS Code) of one theme while using the editor colours from a .tmTheme file?

Is the only way to do this at the time of writing really to set each of my syntax colours individually with `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Combining a VS Code color theme's UI styles with syntax highlighting from an existing `.tmTheme` file

Unfortunately, as of the time of writing this, there's no easy way to accomplish this. After failing several times to accomplish it using VS Code's Yeoman theme generator tool alone, I finally managed to get it working by following [the instructions here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme) and then doing some additional manual work, although I found that this first method was for some reason prone to reverting back. I then figured out a second, more persistent method, and so far this hasn't reverted back.

#### Method 1 (prone to reverting back)

Open the VS Code terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>), and run the following commands to install and run the Yeoman theme generator tool:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
yo code
```

Select `New color theme`, `Start fresh`, then follow the prompts to give your theme names and an ID (hit Enter to leave the description blank). Yeoman will then create a theme folder for your new theme on your desktop.

[image]

Assuming that the theme whose UI styling you want to use as a base is already installed as a VS Code extension, navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`, click into the base theme's folder, and locate its `-color-theme.json` file (usually inside of a `themes` folder).  Copy this file to the `themes` folder of your newly-created theme, making sure to delete the existing `-color-theme.json` in that folder.

Open the newly-copied `-color-theme.json` file and look for the line beginning with `"tokenColors":`. Delete everything after it inside of and including the square brackets:

[image]

...and replace with the name of the `.tmTheme` file containing your syntax highlighting styles:

```
"tokenColors": "syntax-highlighting.tmTheme"
```

Finally, copy your syntax highlighting file to the `themes` folder, and then copy the entire theme folder to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`.

Restart VS Code, and change the active theme (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) to your new theme.

#### Method 2 (persistent)

Open the VS Code terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>), and run the following commands to install and run the Yeoman theme generator tool:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
yo code
```

Select `New color theme`, `Import and inline an existing theme`, and then enter the path to the .tmTheme file whose syntax highlighting styles you want to use. Note that this must be an absolute path without quotes:

[image]

Follow the prompts to give the theme names and an ID (press Enter to leave the description blank), and Yeoman will then create a theme folder for the new theme on your desktop.

Assuming that the theme whose UI styling you want to use as a base is already installed as a VS Code extension, navigate to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`, click into the base theme's folder, and locate its  file (usually inside of a `themes` folder).

Copy all the styles inside of this file's `colors` object:

[image]

...and paste them into the `colors` object of the `-color-theme.json` file in the theme folder created by Yeoman, making sure to remove any that exist.

Finally, copy the entire theme folder to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`.

Restart VS Code, and change the active theme (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) to your new theme. If you followed this process correctly, you should now have a VS Code color theme that uses the UI styling of your chosen base theme and the syntax highlighting styles of your chosen .tmTheme file, and doesn't revert back without warning.

[image]